# How to compose the layout of Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, pdf, layout, r-markdown

I am trying to design a report. I have several chunks above this one. The structure of my Rmarkdown file is like this:

```
# loding libraries
```

```
# This is a chunk for a function
```

```
# This is a chunk for plots
```

```
tbl_img = data.frame(
  Categories = c("Family Health Rountines", "Parents Health Behaviors", "Test Column"),
  "Family Health Rountines" = ""
)

tbl_img %>%
  kbl(booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_paper(full_width = F) %>%
  column_spec(column = 2, image = spec_image(c("p1.png", "p2.png", "p3.png"), width = 1000, height = 70))
```

Here is how it knit: [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0BBP.png)

I thought this output should be shown at the top of the document. However, it has been posted at the bottom. Do anyone know how to modify this?

Thank you!

I have totally no idea how to resolve this problem.

Comment: This is due to latex formatting - can you use the HTML output? Or do you need the PDF output?

Comment: I would try adding `kable_styling(latex_options = "HOLD_position")` to the pipeline

Comment: @mfg3z0 Unfortunately, I need the PDF output.

Comment: [Here is an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/542466/centering-plot-in-rmarkdown-pdf-displays-latex-code-in-output-begincenter-l) to a very similar question on the LaTeX StackExchange site about formatting plots in RMarkdown - I think this might be the solution you need. The suggestion is to export your table/plot as an image, and then load in the image to format as desired